# If user is logged-in display/hide something

Tags: functions, login, content

I want to check at page load if the user is logged in or not and hide the login mask I programmed accordingly. There is a reason I'm using said login mask instead of redirecting to the WordPress standard login.

The idea was to use functions.php:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo '<li id="text-2" style="display:none;">';
} else {
    echo '<li id="text-2">'; }
```

This code works, but my page kind of stops loading after that.
And if I pack the entire thing into a function I get an error - **Parse error has been resolved by Answer01 by Brad Dalton.**

Long story short: **How do I show/hide certain elements depending on whether a user is logged in or not?**

**edit01:** Here's the parts before the code I posted above:

```
<?php

function modify_user_contact_methods($user_contact) {
    // Add new fields
    $user_contact['uidnumber'] = 'UID-Nummer';
    return $user_contact;
}

add_filter('user_contactmethods', 'modify_user_contact_methods');

?>
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo '<li id="text-2" style="display:none;">';
} else {
    echo '<li id="text-2">';
 }
?>
```

**edit02:** I've tried using the code provided below with the action_hook:

```
add_action( 'loop_start', 'loginCheck' );
function loginCheck() {
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo '<li id="text-2" class="hidden">';
} else {
    echo '<li id="text-2">';
 }
}
```

Yet now the page looks like this: - **solved in edit03**

**edit03:** I've used a temporary work-around by switching loop_start with loop_end.
However as I said earlier, the section I want to hide is still being displayed.

**edit04:** WP_DEBUG.. let's see.. - **no relevant finding related to the problem**

**edit05:** ***So here's the summary of the current situation:***

- Page is loading, all elements are displayed, check.
- jQuery opens and closes the Login-Box if the user is not logged in,
  check.
- Content is hidden when user is logged in to prevent confusion,
  UNSOLVED.

So essentially it's only the function that doesn't do what it's supposed to.

Here's a link to the website: [easy2work.at](http://www.easy2work.at/)

What I want is to hide the "Firmen-Login | Anmelden" once the user is logged in and display something else up there which is ready to be implemented.

Comment: Read your syntax error message, there is some syntax missing before your funtion call, something like a comma, semi-colon, bracket, full stop etc.

Comment: I tried using add_action('init', loginCheck); already. same error.

Comment: Without seeing the code, it is impossible to say what exactly is causing the error. Post the effected section of code in an [edit] please. Do not post code in comments as it is unreadable

Comment: enable `WP_DEBUG` to `true` to see what's the inner problem resides there after.

Comment: The edit is much better. Please ask one specific question at a time, that is policy and will also not cause confusion

Comment: I'm still asking the same question I did an hour ago. There's just been so much information added all around it that it was getting confusing, even for me. Therefore I have shortened the question by simply removing irrelevant or solved parts by pointing at the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code won't work in a themes functions file unless it includes a hook.

Try something like:

```
add_action( 'loop_start', 'your_function' );
function your_function() {

if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo '<li id="text-2" class="hide">';
} else {
    echo '<li id="text-2">'; 
}}
```

Comment: So the site is loading again, yet nothing changed concerning my mentioned problem.
Also the site stops loading after the header (see above)

Comment: So here's the current situation: Site is loading, jQuery does what it's supposed to. Only this function does not want to work.
I'll add **edit05** and try to be as exact as possible.